# How to get Signed 32-bit integer place value number mathematically?

Tags: c#

I have a number (*ideally I would like to do this for any place value*).

```
Int32 _num = 2147483647;
```

And I would like to get the millions place value (7)?

I can sell out and say

```
 Int32 _num = 2147483647;
 string str_num = _num.ToString().Substring(3).Remove(1);
```

Or,

```
int millions = (_num / 1000000) % 10;
```

There must be a way to get the 7 in the millions spot without doing any Substrings,Removes or Modulus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question was changed to not include the modulus operator:

```
(num / 1000000) - (num / 10000000)*10
```

Though since that involves extra operations, it is more expensive that just using `%` and less intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
int millions = (_num / 1000000) % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide, and then just get the ten. `(2147483647 / 1000000) % 10`

Comment: Thanks...Modulus seems like the only way

Comment: The OP asked for an answer that doesn't use modulus.

Comment: Modulus was added as an edit later. The original question did not include that at all, only the string operation.